# Android for work - How to check if my application is running in the work profile?

Tags: android

I'm creating an app that needs to behave differently if it's running in the work profile.

There is any possibility to know that?

The documentation has nothing about it and I already tried to add a restriction that is only available in the work profile and it works, but I need a solution without any action from the administrator.

Android for work information:
http://www.android.com/work/

Android for work documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/index.html

Comment: Did you manage to identify when an app is running on work profile or not?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If you find anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a solution :
if isProfileOwnerApp return true for one package name, it means that your app (badged) is running on work profile.
if your app is running in normal mode (no badge) isProfileOwnerApp return false for all admins even if there is a Work profile.

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
List<ComponentName> activeAdmins =   devicePolicyManager.getActiveAdmins();
if (activeAdmins != null){
   for (ComponentName admin : activeAdmins){
      String packageName=  admin.getPackageName();
      Log.d(TAG, "admin:"+packageName);
      Log.d(TAG, "profile:"+ devicePolicyManager.isProfileOwnerApp(packageName));
      Log.d(TAG, "device:"+ devicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp(packageName));
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's a `work profile`? or are all profiles work profiles?

Comment: @Jason  `if (devicePolicyManager.isProfileOwnerApp(packageName)) return true;` inside the loop, if one package return true, then you are in work profile. Otherwise, you are not.

Comment: in my case i am getting both false in Xiaomi and activeadmins null in one plus, i am using Island app for work profile.

Answer (score 2):

I took the response from @earlypearl into a Kotlin class:

```kotlin
class UserProfile(context: Context) {
    private val weakContext = WeakReference(context)

    val isInstalledOnWorkProfile: Boolean
        get() {
            return weakContext.get()?.let {
                val devicePolicyManager =
                    it.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
                val activeAdmins = devicePolicyManager.activeAdmins

                activeAdmins?.any { devicePolicyManager.isProfileOwnerApp(it.packageName) } ?: false
            } ?: false
        }
}
```