# How can I tell if my android app is running in Intune

Tags: android, mdm, intune

How can I tell programatically if my Android application has been wrapped by Microsoft's Intune MDM. I'm not going to be able to link to the Intune SDK.

Comment: Do you know any class that microsoft Intune has then its easy to find if it' wrapped or not

Comment: If its Android for Work/MDM profile then check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442121/android-for-work-how-to-check-if-my-application-is-running-in-the-work-profile