# How to check whether my app is running inside work/personal profile?

Tags: android

Consider a use case like, in a device [testDPC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afwsamples.testdpc&hl=en) app is installed and is running as a profile owner. My app ABC have installed and it is having two instance one is running inside the work profile(Badged) another is in personal profile(Non badged). Now I need to check programatically in my app whether it is in work/personal profile.

[Android for work - How to check if my application is running in the work profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442121/android-for-work-how-to-check-if-my-application-is-running-in-the-work-profile)

The answer above will not help me as it uses DevicePolicyManger which is only available for testDpc.

Also I could not find any flag indicating in ApplicationInfo api for the above
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any answer for this?