# Device Owner on Android box with Android 10 is not working

Tags: android, shell, device-owner

I am facing an issue while trying to make applying device owner on Android 10 devices

More details:

1. I am applying it on Android box with android version 10
2. I am trying to do that through ADB command.
   adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.android.testapp/.receivers.AdminReceiver
3. The same command is working fine on android 8 and previous android versions

Current command output is: (on early OS version it's returned success)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't set package ComponentInfo{.(already filled)./.(already filled).AdminReceiver} as device owner.
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:204)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:115)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:56)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:41)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:338)
```

Update: this is the device policy details
[image]

Any advice

Comment: Wondering if there is an existing device owner: [Checking if there is already a work profile, who owns it and if it is active](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50835172/295004)

Comment: Checked, there is no device admin, also I formate factory reset for the device